# Prepared statement returning zero results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to execute the following prepared statement:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT * FROM Inventory I WHERE I.ParentId = ?';
EXECUTE stmt USING @parentId;
```

`DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;`

When I execute this statement, it returns the column headers with no rows.  It should return 6 rows.

If I execute this same statement as a normal SQL statement without the PREPARE and EXECUTE statement, I get results, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Inventory I WHERE I.ParentId = parentId;
```

Results are returned.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there some kind of casting going on that is making my statement invalidate?

Update, parentId is passed in as a parameter, e.g.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`george`@`%` PROCEDURE `ListInventoryByParentId`(IN parentId INT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User variable @parentId and procedure argument parentID are independent.
You need to set your user variable to procedure argument before executing statement.

```
SET @parentID = parentId;
```